# Yup phone number validation doesn't works

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, yup

I have next form and formik:

```
const formik = useFormik( {
    initialValues: {
      number: '',
    },
    onSubmit: values => {
      action( values.number );
    },
    validationSchema: numberSchema,
  } );

  return (
    <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
      <SomeForm>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="some-number">
          <FormattedMessage {...messages.number} />
        </InputLabel>
        <Input
          value={formik.values.number}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          id="number"
          type="tel"
          placeholder="+1 (000) 000 0000"
        />
.
.
.
```

and schema looks like:

```
const numberSchema = Yup.object( {
    number:
        Yup.number().typeError( "That doesn't look like a phone number" )
            .required( 'Phone number is required!' )
            .positive()
            .min( 7 )
} );
```

Issue is in validating count of entered digits, when I enter only one digit I'am getting error that number should be greater than or equal to 7, but after second entering, this error message disappears. Why it stops validating after more then 1 digit entered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are validating it as a number and not as a string, thus `.min` in this case means that number value has to be minimum 7. It's not a length. You have to validate it as a string and use a regexp pattern. Example:

```
phoneSchema = Yup.string().matches(new RegExp('[0-9]{7}'))
```

And then you can also make it more advanced.